# Deploying project from server to server

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Dev - QA - Prod SSIS server setup.

The project is ready for deployment to QA. What would be the minimal rights required for a user on Dev to read the project and on QA to deploy it?

Comment: Could you clarify "read the project". How are you going to perform the deploy (double click the .ispac file, Visual Studio deploy, TSQL, etc)?

Comment: Planning on right-click on the destination server's "Projects/Deploy Project"